# Ember setupController and transient controllers

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use `setupController` method to pass some data to the controller from the route and it only works if the controller is a singleton.

The `setupController` method is called in both situations but the variables are only set on the controller if it's a singleton.

How can I pass data from a route to a transient controller?

Here's a twiddle:
http://ember-twiddle.com/ba55734e925664e363f4

Uncomment/comment the following line to toggle between singleton/transient:
`//application.register('controller:application', 'ApplicationController', { singleton: false });`

I have not been able to find any information about whether or not this should work. I'm using Ember 1.13.6.

*controllers/application.js:*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName:'Ember Twiddle'
});
```

*initializers/application.js:*

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
 //application.register('controller:application', 'ApplicationController', { singleton: false });
}

export default {
  name: 'application-init',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

*routes/application.js:*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller,model) {
    this._super(controller,model);
    controller.var1 = "Variable 1";
  }
});
```

*templates/application.hbs:*

```
<h1>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
<br>
<br>
{{var1}}
<br>
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would be highly surprised if this is supposed to work. Ember assumes singleton controllers nearly everywhere. Most of the time it doesn't pass around controller references, it just looks the controller up from the container again (which in your case would cause it to be re-created).

Comment: Y U DO DIS? Seriously, that's some heavy counter-Ember-way stuff.

Comment: That's not how you set things, use the set and get method to interact with properties, setting them directly won't fire any bindings, and controllers are singletons for a reason.

Comment: I responded with a solution and explanation on the forum: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/setupcontroller-method-and-transient-controller/8517/3?u=jasonmit

Comment: @Kitler assigning properties directly doesn't make a difference vs. using `set`. Also, it is possible to create transient controllers for a reason too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an actual bug, since the instance of the controller is different from the instance you have in setupController and the one backing the view.

A workaround would be overriding the renderTemplate hook on your route to pass the instance of the controller versus a string reference which is looked up by default (and creating a new instance of the controller!).

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    controller.set('var1', 'foo');
  },
  renderTemplate(controller, model) {
    // note: don't call super here
    this.render('application', {
      controller: controller,
      model: model
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work as a work-around. I'll wait for the confirmation of this being a bug on Github before accepting as an answer.